# Forking vs overriding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am working on a reasonably large and quite customised ruby on rails spree commerce installation. I am trying to decide how best to architect it so that I can keep upgrading spree without fear of it breaking my modifications.

In the past I have followed the general spree documentation and made modifications by using decorators, overrides and sometimes overriding views completely. This works fine however there are two issues.

1.) It can be harder to reason about the program when classes are opened up and extended via decorators. Its much easier if you can open up the file eg Spree::Product and look at the code and then work your way up the ancestors rather than knowing that in various parts in your system the class is being opened up and modified.

2.) It can be hard to upgrade Spree if you go down this route. If you have overridden a view and it changes in the next version of spree you have no way of knowing. All you can do is upgrade and hope that one of your tests or manual testing picks it up if it breaks.

The benefit of the above however is of course that its a very easy way to get started with modifications and if you are making few and small modifications then its probably fine.

However are there better alternatives? One approach that I have been considering is simply forking Spree and making the changes directly in the forked spree codebase. I could then simply pull any new changes from spree into my forked repo when I want to upgrade. The advantage of this approach is that git will notify me whenever there is a change in a view that I have overridden. I can then merge this manually and either ignore it or take action. Has anyone in here done this in practice? Are there any drawbacks that I am overlooking?

Comment: I think that you will have a lot of changes and you will have to sort out what you changed vs what spree changed.

It will most likely be more painful than the spree proposed approch which you were using. At least you can write tests for each of the methods you are overriding and see if they still pass after the upgrade.

I would personally not upgrade Spree unless new features are available which I require in the software and this can usually be forecasted looking at the upcoming features.

For one of my clients we used an older version just to keep the same codebase across multiple stores.

Answer (score 0):

Spree is still in rapid development. Each minor version bump has marked differences from the previous version. Some of these changes are bad, most of these changes are good. If you're running Spree 2.0 for example it's beneficial to upgrade because of the shipping overhaul, and as we get close to 2.2.3/2.3 there are a number of optimizations and refactoring coming down the pipe.

Most stores using spree tend to have large codebases, or depend on a large number of extensions. While I agree that going to class_eval for everything is generally frowned upon it is better than forking the spree project yourself. We've had a spree fork that we've had to maintain for one of our projects and it usually involves sometimes painful re-bases in order to get the benefits coming down from spree proper. Generally, I think writing extensions or decorating classes is the best way to customize your application, sure when things upgrade things break. It usually takes less time to fix the things that break than to maintain a seperate spree fork, given you're responsibly decorating.

It is your decision on how you modify classes and views. There are ways of doing it that are less intrusive and therefore more flexible when change comes. There is straight redefining methods when a before filter would do, or copying a view when an override would do, these are choices that you have to make when weighing the cost of doing it the nice way vs maintaining your own custom functionality.

TL;DR unless you're making a change to spree you'd like to send back to spree as a pr, I would recommend avoiding forking spree just to customize it for your purposes. It is a large source of technical debt if you ever aim to move to newer versions.